# passing the Drop down selected values to query string spring hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to pass the dropdown slected values to DAOimpl for a query to be fire on the selected items.

in my JSP

```
  <form:form method="post" action="searchctr" modelAttribute="tobe">   
     <form:select path="teams.teamId"">    
       <option value="0">Select a type</option>
       <c:forEach items="${teamKey}" var="teams">
          <option value="${teams.teamId}" >${teams.teamName}</option>
       </c:forEach>
 </form:select>
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 form-group">
                        <fmt:message key="button.search" />
                    </button>
```

In my conroller

```
@RequestMapping(value="searchctr", method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected ModelAndView showSearchForm(@ModelAttribute Tobe tobe, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, Model model)throws Exception{


    return new ModelAndView("asset/someform", model.asMap());
}
```

How can i read the selected values of dropdown and pass them to DAOimpl to build the query.

Answer (score 1):

The `<form:select path="teams.teamId"">` should be replaced with somethin like

```
<form:select path="teamId">
```

and the `Tobe` pojo bean should have `setTeamId()/getTeamId()` methods. Then ust read the selected value using the `getTeamId()` in the controller.

Comment: This will work for user. Only he needs to check wheathr teamId attribute is in Tobe Pojo